# Activate Windows Server 2012 R2 on Windows Instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm currently a client of GCP. I have a Windows Instance, with Windows Server 2012 R2 and everything has been running smoothly for a couple of months now.

Last week I started receiving a notification on my VM's desktop to activate Windows Server 2012 R2, which is odd since this should be taken care of by GCP at the creation and start of the windows instance.

My support level is bronze, which means i can't get anybody to help me fix this issue.  As i need to enter a product key to activate the Server license.

I don't think i should subscribe to a Silver or Gold level, just to fix this issue, which should have been taken care of already.

What can i do, to get the windows license activated?

Comment: Have you tried following the normal steps.i.e. click on activateNow ? This warning doesn't necessarily mean you don't have a license, just that is not activated.

Comment: Hi...Thanks for your reply. Yep, went to control panel/system, activate windows. But I need to enter a product key. Should i subscribe to silver level, just to have this sorted?

If i do end up subscribing, do you know if i can unsubscribe immediately after activating the server?

Comment: In this case you might be better posting your question in the dedicated google group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gce-discussion Its seems a lot more active in regards to GCE assistance. Also here if you are still in the trial - https://support.google.com/cloud/troubleshooter/6275061

Answer (score 0):

We had same issue pop up out of nowhere.  We had higher level of support with google.  they had advised it was a bug related to our use of a NAT gateway and provided a work around of adding a public IP to our vms.  This worked, we would add the ephemeral public IP, activate windows and then remove it.  They did report this as resolved a few months ago and we have not seen the issue since.